# Linux: maven resources:copy-resources plugin. Parameter with space character

Tags: linux, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have pom with resources:copy-resources plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>preprocess</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>source</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And I try to run this plugin with param:

```
sudo bash mvnw.sh process-resources -DvalidationQuery="select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1"
```

Error is:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "1". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

---

```
-DvalidationQuery="\"select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1\""
-DvalidationQuery="""select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1"""
"-DvalidationQuery=select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1"
```

doesn't work

---

`sudo bash mvnw.sh process-resources -DvalidationQuery="blabla"` - works

With windows os I don't have similar problem.

How can I use param with space?

Comment: Please show the full pom file and the content of mvnw.sh ?

Comment: Pom added. mvnw.sh : https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper/blob/master/mvnw  Plugin works correct with params without space.

Comment: If this is the full pom file why do you need the system property? I don't see a location where it is used ? Furthermore looks like a problem with `mvnw.sh` script...

Answer (score 0):

`sudo bash mvnw.sh process-resources "\"-DvalidationQuery=select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1\""` works